# how to target last tr in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to apply some css properties on last tr in table so i have use :last selector but it wont work in ie9 below version so i am trying to do so with "eq()" method but not getting result. It is possible to target last tr with eq() method in jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var trNo= $('#compareTable tr');
    var NoN= trNo.eq(-1);
    NoN.css('border','none')
    });


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="main">

<div class="compatible">
<h4 class="compatileHeading">8 Matching Compatible Product</h4>
<div class="listingCompatibleProdcut">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="compareTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="105" align="center">
    <div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="105" align="center">
    <div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
    <td width="105" align="center"><div class="compareBox">
    <ul id="compareunorderedList">
    <li class="compareImg"><img src="images/img.jpg" width="50" height="93" /></li>
    <li class="compareTitle">Galaxy S LCD 4GB</li>
    <li class="compareCode">GT-19003</li>


    </ul>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>



</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#compareTable tr').last().css('border', '0');
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
  $('#compareTable tr:last-child').css('border', '0');
});
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/edLev/

Comment: not working in ie even i used eq() method but it is also not working in ie

Comment: Exactly. A `tr` doesn't have a border. You can only draw borders around the whole table or around individual cells. And this is not an IE problem

Comment: @amit Now I read the question again, I'm having doubts about what you try to do. There are no borders to begin with (you explicitly state `border="0"`), so `border:none` wouldn't have any effect even if it would work.

Comment: This is educational though. When I was experimenting, I discovered that the jQuery `$('#compareTable tr:last-child')...` works even in older browsers that don't have `<style> tr:last-child {...}` implemented. That opens possibilities!

Comment: @amit @MrLister Using `border-collapse: collapse;` on the table makes it possible to draw borders arround `tr`, though this then even works in my IE8.

Comment: @MrLister - All of the [selectors that jQuery supports](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) should work in all browsers. That's the point, jQuery doesn't depend on native support of the equivalent CSS selector to work.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery implements the [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/), so this should work:

```
$('#compareTable tr:last')

// or, for better performance

$('#compareTable tr').filter(':last')
```

Having said that, `.eq(-1)` should work too...

EDIT: I just tried `:last` and `.eq(-1)` with your html and both worked fine in both Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way i can think of is:

```
$("#compareTable tr:last-child")
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)